# How to handle summary/report in CQRS?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, idempotent

I'm working on a hotel reservation project. A new feature requires that customer could comment on hotels. Each comment has a rating ( 0 --> 5). On search hotel page, each hotel shows its average rating.

The comment adding is quite easy, and an CommentAddedEvent could be published:

```
class CommentAddedEvent {
    private String hotelId;
    private double rating;
    //other attributes omitted
}
```

On the query side, a comment row is persisted on this event:

```
 create table t_comment {
    hotel_id number,
    rating   number(2,1)
}
```

But we're slowed down on how to show hotel's average rating. The following are our potential solutions:

**a) Database integration**

On the search hotel query side, use sql function to get the average:

```
select h.id, h.name,....,select avg(c.rating) from t_commentc , t_hotel 
where.... group by c.hotel_id.....
```

This looks easy, but we think it introduce more effort on test, and may cause some performance issues.

**b) EventHandler calculating average**

Add an event handler subscribing CommentAddedEvent and calculates average:

```
public void on(CommentAddedEvent event) {
    Hotel hotel = ....
    double total = hotel.rating * hotel.comments;
    double average = (total + event.rating)/(hotel.comments + 1)
    //update hotel
}
```

The test is easy but this solution seems not to be idempotent. The event handler may handle duplicate event when something fails.

**c) Scheduled task**

Add a scheduled task, summary each hotel's comments. But this is inefficient for some hotels are not commented since the last task.

**d) Scheduled task mixed with event handler**

Use an event handler to mark hotels commented since last task:

```
public void on(CommentAddedEvent event) {
    int count = uncalculatedCommentsOnHotel(...);
    count++;
    //update count
}
```

And schedule the summary task based on hotels having count greater than zero.

Solution D is idempotent and seems to be more effective. Is there some flaws we made or any other solutions?

Comment: How about keeping on the *read model*, for each hotel, the *number of comments it gets* and *an aggregation (sum) of scores* (stars etc.). That is, on each *CommentAddedEvent*, the handler simply increments the comments counter and adds something to the sum of scores. Then, when querying the read model... you simply read those values for a specific hotel. Of course, on the read-model table / view you may add a "computed" column, average = *your formula* :) What do you think?

Comment: @andrei But keep a counter in the handler will make the handler a stateful bean?

Comment: I thought of something like retrieving the current counters from the read model and incrementing them. Then, I guess the read model can be simply rebuild from events when necessary.

Comment: any full sample  code about it?

Answer (score 3):

I would choose to implement an event handler calculating the average (option b). You have a couple of strategies for overcoming the idempotency issue.

1. **Make the message handler idempotent** by adding conditional checking within the handler using a correlation identifier. In this case you could track the Id of comments already processed for each hotel to prevent and only process new comments.

   ```
   public void on(CommentAddedEvent event) 
   {       
       Hotel hotel = ....

       if (hotel.CommentIds.Contains(event.CommentId))
           return;  // comment has already been processed

       double total = hotel.rating * hotel.comments;
       double average = (total + event.rating)/(hotel.comments + 1)

       hotel.CommentIds.Add(event.CommentId);
       //update hotel
   }
   ```
2. **De-dupe messages at the infrastructure level.** When an event is received, it could be checked against an event store. If the message already appears in the event store, then it can be safely discarded. This would ensure each event handler receives the event at most once.

By moving the de-duplication responsibility out to the infrastructure it means that you do not need to make each event handler idempotent. This would allow your original option b handler to work, as-is.

**Further Reading**

- [(Un) Reliability in messaging: idempotency and de-duplication](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/06/03/un-reliability-in-messaging-idempotency-and-de-duplication/) by Jimmy Bogard
- [Idempotency Patterns](http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/2010/04/idempotency-patterns/) by Jonathan Oliver

Comment: Nice suggestion and articles. The only risk I could think of is high contention although not possible in my hotel comment case. But how about something sumup frequently, like page visited count or something like that?